# How to deal with "undefined label XXX" in Go assembly for libc functions like malloc?

Tags: go, assembly, malloc, x86-64

I found a project [c2goasm](https://github.com/fwessels/c2goasm) that can convert assembly from a C compiler into Golang assembly, but I'm currently having some problems.

such as **"linkedlist.c"** :

```
void ListNodeCreat(int val, struct ListNode* ret) {
    struct ListNode * node = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    node->val = val;
    node->next = NULL;
    ret = node;
}
```

The generated C assembly file **"linkedlist.s"** is as follows, in GNU assembler `.intel_syntax noprefix`

```
ListNodeCreat:                          # @ListNodeCreat
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    and rsp, -16
    sub rsp, 32
    mov dword ptr [rsp + 28], edi
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 16], rsi
    mov edi, 16
    call    malloc
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
    mov ecx, dword ptr [rsp + 28]
    mov rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
    mov dword ptr [rax], ecx
    mov rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
    mov qword ptr [rax + 8], 0
    mov rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Pay attention to the "**call    malloc**" in it，when using **c2goasm** to get go assembly **"linkedlist_amd64.s"**, it still exists:

```
TEXT ·_ListNodeCreat(SB), $40-16
    MOVQ val+0(FP), DI
    MOVQ ret+8(FP), SI
    ADDQ $8, SP
    LONG $0x1c247c89             // mov    dword [rsp + 28], edi
    LONG $0x24748948; BYTE $0x10 // mov    qword [rsp + 16], rsi
    LONG $0x000010bf; BYTE $0x00 // mov    edi, 16
    CALL malloc
    LONG $0x24448948; BYTE $0x08 // mov    qword [rsp + 8], rax
    LONG $0x1c244c8b             // mov    ecx, dword [rsp + 28]
    LONG $0x24448b48; BYTE $0x08 // mov    rax, qword [rsp + 8]
    WORD $0x0889                 // mov    dword [rax], ecx
    LONG $0x24448b48; BYTE $0x08 // mov    rax, qword [rsp + 8]
    QUAD $0x000000000840c748     // mov    qword [rax + 8], 0
    LONG $0x24448b48; BYTE $0x08 // mov    rax, qword [rsp + 8]
    LONG $0x24448948; BYTE $0x10 // mov    qword [rsp + 16], rax
    SUBQ $8, SP
    RET
```

so when I run "go build" or "go tool asm linkedlist_amd64.s", I got:

```
linkedlist_amd64.s:28: undefined label malloc
asm: assembly of linkedlist_amd64.s failed
```

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Does Go link the C run-time (libc.so)?  Does Go allocate memory using that malloc, or does it have its own runtime?

Comment: `ADDQ $8, SP` - That doesn't look right; you never want to be adding a positive number to the stack pointer (deallocating space) in the function prologue.  Notice how the clang-generated code reserves 32 bytes of space with `sub rsp, 32`.  (What options did you compile with?  The compiler should know that the incoming RSP is 16-byte aligned already, unless you use weird options to tell it the incoming stack alignment is less than required for making further calls.)

Comment: To whoever is about to comment: note that Go assembler [has certain conventions](https://go.dev/doc/asm) which could look weird if interpreted verbatim.

Comment: `c2goasm` is a tool that cannot blindly be used.  You'll have to know exactly what you are doing.  It is certainly not possible to take arbitrary C code, compile it, and then translate the assembly code.  Especially code that calls other functions or code that allocates memory is pretty much right out.

Comment: @PeterCordes, FWIW, Go runtime has its own allocator. It never calls `malloc` even in cases `libc` is linked in.

Comment: @kostix It does if you call `C.CString` or various other cgo support functions.

Comment: @fuz, that's not Go runtime, but your own code ;-) I have interpreted Peter's question may be too precise, but the Go runtime does not call out to C to allocate "its own" objects—like when the `new()` function gets executed and in similar cases.

Comment: @kostix That is correct.